UI Kitten - List Component - Set Text Font Style
I am building a React Native app and have successfully implemented the UI Kitten components ad set custom colors. I am unable to find out how to set the text color and font size however.
      <ListItem
        textStyle={{ fontSize: 28, fontWeight: "bold" }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: item._id === selectedIndex ? "yellow" : "white",
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }}
        title={`${item.requests.projectname} ${item.requests.requestname}`}
        description={`${format(
          item.requestbids.deliverydate,
          "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
        )} ${item.requestbids.status}`}
        accessoryLeft={(props) =>
          renderItemIcon({ ...{ selectedItem: item, ...props } })
        }
        accessoryRight={(props) =>
          renderItemAccessory({ ...{ selectedItem: item, ...props } })
        }
        backgroundColor="#f9c2ff"
        onPress={(index) => {
          setSelectedIndex(item._id);
        }}
      />

The code above has no effect. Please advise.
